# Не возвращает JSON ответ, при запросе, Java

Tags: java, json, api, http

Учусь работать с апи на примере api.owencloud.ru, отправляю JSON пост запрос. Возвращает код 302 и в response получаю null, хотя по идее должен получать JSON ответ, что я делаю не так?

```
public class authentication {
    private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    private static String host_url = "http://api.owencloud.ru";
    private static String post_authentication = "/v1/auth/open";
    private static Person person = new Person("test", "test");
    private static String authentication_json = GSON.toJson(person);
    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = host_url + post_authentication;
        URL obj = new URL(null, url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setDoOutput(true);

        String urlParameters = authentication_json;

        // Send post request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        authentication http = new authentication();

        System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
        http.sendPost();

    }
}

class Person {
    private String login;
    private String password;

    public Person(String login, String password) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, происходит попытка перенаправление на URL, использующий отличный от HTTP протокол (например, https). В таком случае, автоматическое перенаправление работать не будет.

Необходимо добавить дополнительную логику для такого перенаправления. Вот тут есть пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26046079/8343843

**P.S.** - либо просто попробуйте использовать `https://api.owencloud.ru` вместо `http://api.owencloud.ru`

Comment: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL если меняю на https

Comment: Значит, вариант из ссылки

Comment: Ну в браузере когда вводишь https все норм, может в коде чтото не так прописываю

Comment: Да, похоже. Если сделать `curl -X POST https://api.owencloud.ru/v1/auth/open` то json возвращается с кодом `401`. Ищите корни новой проблемы в `GSON.toJson(person);`

Comment: Видимо таких креденшелов как `test/test` не существует. Попробуйте воспользоваться реальными.

Comment: Да, как только воспользовался реальными все заработало. Спасибо